# SQL Server services could not be started as 2 instances sharing same 'model' file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please advise me on this issue:

I have one default instance in SQL Server 2005 (sp 3 x64 bits) called `instanceA`. Then I installed another 2 instances called `instanceB` and `C`.

After that I restore `master.bak` from production server to this `instanceB`. The SQL Server services for this instance could not be started at all since then. If I turned off the default instance services, instanceB can be started. This is because both of the instances are pointing to the same `model.mdf` file in `MSSQL.1` folder. Hence both instances could not be started simultaneously.

I believe that in production server, the model path is configured to the default folder `MSSQL.1` .Is there anyway to change the path to `MSSQL.8` that belongs to `instanceB` upon installation so that both instances A and B could be started together?

How to change the path of pointing to the correct model file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The paths of the other system databases (`model`, `msdb`, and `tempdb`) can be changed using [`ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx). The changes take effect on instance restart.

I blogged about how to move all the system databases [here](http://voluntarydba.com/post/2012/09/06/Moving-the-System-Databases.aspx), including a video demo of the whole process. (The demos shows 2008 R2, but it's the same for 2005.) In your case, the files are already in the spot you want, so all you need to do is change the paths.